# How to run a grunt task without writing a file?

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way where one can just dry run a grunt task and see what the output would be if it was an actual file? I am using grunt requirejs task but need to check if it is properly configured.

Note: *"grunt requirejs --no-write" does not work for me*

```
grunt.initConfig({
    requirejs: {
            task: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "a/b/c/directory",
                    mainConfigFile: "a/b/c/grunt_main.js",
                    name: "../grunt_main",
                    excludeShallow: ["../grunt_main"],
                    out: "a/b/c/directory/<%= version.name %>.js",
                    optimize: "uglify",
                    preserveLicenseComments: false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "--no-write does not work for me"? `--no-write` seems the perfect fit for what you want to do!?

Comment: Even when I am adding this option, a new file is generated as if it is an actual grunt task

Comment: It works with other packages though. Example: 'grunt cssmin --no-write' works like charm.

Comment: you could set the `out`-option to `"stdout"`. see here: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L462

Comment: Works! Also is there a way to just check what source files will be used to make a destination files without running the task actually? I am using mainConfigFile option over here.

Comment: see here: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L452. i think sourceMapsText helps you there

Comment: Nope! It still runs the task.

Comment: dont know how to help you then. maybe you describe in your question WHY you want to do that (can't think about 1 reason), and maybe there are better solutions...

Comment: Need to check if files that were updated in the latest 'git pull' are listed in the source files of 'grunt requirejs' task. This will help me decide whether or not to run the grunt task.

Comment: there is no way to do that, without actually running the task. you could run the task output to some tmp directory, do your check and delete the generated tmp-data afterwards